# Unable to interpret LOOP Results

Tags: regression, stata

I have never used loop before but I am looking at the change of gender wage differential in Vietnam after the implementation of the Doi Moi Reform in 1986. I conducted Oaxaca decompositions but my Professor suggested I run LOOP in order to see the effect on each age especially because I only have 2004 data NOT a panel data. So I was wondering how can I interpret these Loop results. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

[image: Loop Results to Interpret]

**NOTE THAT "young" is a dummy variable where 0=OLD and 1=YOUNG. OLD are ages 38-59 years and YOUNG are ages 19-37. I separated the two groups to see who was most affected by the reform. **

Comment: What is `loop` or `LOOP` or `Loop`? No results are readable here. If this is about interpretation, and not about your code, you are in the wrong place: try Statalist or Cross Validated. (Spelling is `Stata`, not `STATA`.)

Comment: The results are now readable (thanks to an edit). It seems that your reference to a loop means _only_ that you have multiple regressions with different response (outcome, dependent) variables. You are in the wrong place: this is about fairly elementary statistics, not a problem with programming. I can't see what sense it makes to regard `sex` as a response here.

Comment: Just to put you on the right track, Danah, I suggest that you ask your teacher again about what he is suggesting before posting the question at Cross Validated. Your teacher cannot be possibly suggesting what you are doing: there is no `LOOP` procedure in Stata, and your actual `foreach` loop does not produce adequate models. At that stage, you need to detail your research design and transcribe your teacher's suggestion properly, or it will be impossible to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more related to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). That being said, I also agree that  there is no requirement of `Loop` here unless you are regressing wage on each independent variable one at a time.

Here is what you may want to do  for analyzing the change of gender wage differential across each age. Since you say that the data is cross-sectional (relating to year 2004), I assume that years and yearsq are respectively age and agesq. Your main interest lies in the coefficient of agesex.

```
gen agesex=age*sex   #create interaction variable

regress wage age agesq sex agesex benefits ind edu urb
```

Or, if you want to stick on the young/old group you can do like below.

```
 gen ysex=young*sex   #create interaction variable

 regress wage sex ysex benefits ind edu urb
```

Please see [Woolridge (4e)](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introductory_econometrics.html?id=64vt5TDBNLwC) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is greatly appreciated. I shall try this out.